# Nested try statements to open an XL sheet

Tags: python, try-catch, xlrd

I am trying to open a worksheet in XL. The worksheet could be named as 'Map', 'map' or 'MAP'

This is what I am doing

```
import xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook(xls) // where xls is the name of the spreadsheet
try:
     sheet = book.sheet_by_name('map')
except:
     try:
        sheet = book.sheet_by_name('Map')
     except:
        try:
          sheet = book.sheet_by_name('MAP')
        except:
           raise
```

This looks pretty clunky... is there a more pythonic way of doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is not exactly as readable as some other methods, probably the shortest way is to use:

```
sheet = book.sheet_by_name(list(set(['map', 'Map', 'MAP']) & set(book.sheet_names())[0])
```

Basically, this uses the concept of list intersection presented via another SO answer. Probably an easier way to create this so it easier to read:

```
possibleNames = ['map', 'Map', 'MAP']
sheetNames = book.sheet_names()
name = intersect(possibleNames, sheetNames)
if len(name) < 1:
    print "Error"
    # break program appropiately
sheet = book.sheet_by_name(name[0])

def intersect(a, b):
    return list(set(a) & set(b))
```

Comment: There's also the possibility that more than one name might work, e.g., maybe both Map and MAP exist.  The iteration method lets you decide which name overrides.  Using `[0]` just picks them in whatever order the `set` code chose, not necessarily what one might want.  The `set` method will be faster if you a long list of possible names, though, and is good to keep in mind for other situations. :-)

Comment: @torek: Try creating a workbook in excel with 2 or 3 such names ... it won't let you.

Comment: @JohnMachin: interesting.  I don't actually use excel, just things that work like it and try to share some of its data formats.  Never tested them out for case sensitivity.

Answer (score 4):

Just iterate over the possibilities, trying to open each one in turn:

```
sheet = None
for thing in ['map','Map','MAP']:
  try:
    sheet = book.sheet_by_name(thing)
    break
  except:
    pass
```

After this runs, `sheet` will be set to the first `thing` that could be opened.  If none could be opened, then `sheet` will be `None`.

Comment: +1, I was about to post something similar but you beat me. It would, however, be useful to be able to expicitly handle the case that *none* of the `thing`s worked (where the OP re-raises the last exception) - an `else` clause on the loop is perfect for this. Also, the bare `except:` (like the several similar ones in the OP) should explicitly mention the particular exception that `sheet_by_name` raises if the name is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Excel sheet names are not case-sensitive. Excel will not let you create more than one sheet with a name in (map, Map, MAP, maP, etc) in a single workbook.

```
candidates = [n for n in book.sheet_names() if n.lower() == 'map']
assert len(candidates) in (0, 1)
if candidates:
     sheet = book.sheet_by_name(candidates[0])
else: 
     whatever()
```

Perhaps you'd like to raise an enhancement request asking for Book.sheet_by_name to use a case-insensitive search.